Solving an ODE with a primitive
Can this ODE
$$
(T-t)^2 b^2 (\gamma-1)k'(t) + h(t)k(t) = 0
$$ be solved?
I need to solve this as a part of a larger equation. However, after attempting to use the separation of variables method, I seem to get stuck at the following part:
$$ \ln (k(t)) = \frac{1}{b^2(1-\gamma)} \int_t^T \frac{h(t)}{(T-t)^2}dt
$$
When I try to solve the integral by integration of parts method (where $u = (T-t)^2$ and $v = h(t)$)and taking $H(t)$ to be the primitive of $h(t)$, I do not get a proper answer. Can anyone shed some light on how to solve this? I feel like I am missing an obvious solution.

The integral does not seem to converge. Please check the bounds.

By
$$\frac{k'(t)}{k(t)}=-\frac{h(t)}{b^2 (\gamma -1) (T-t)^2}$$
the solution set is
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \log (k(t,a)) =-\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\left(\int_a^t \frac{h(s)}{b^2 (\gamma -1) (T-s)^2} \, ds\right),$$
possible intervals for $(a,t,T)$ depend on $h.$
